# PHP nested if/else logic

Tags: php, if-statement

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php');

    //error_reporting(0);
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

        $username =$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $ldap = ldap_connect("localserv1.local.local.edu", 389) or exit("Error connecting to LDAP server.");

        //Settings for AD
        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        //Check if user can access LDAP
        if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, 'local\\'.$username, $password)) {
            //Prep SQL statement
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM table WHERE username = ?")) {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();

                // Check if the username is in table
                if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

                    // Log them in
                    session_register("username");
                    session_register("password");
                    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, -9) . "index.php" );
                    exit;

                } else {
                    //User is not in table
                    echo('<p class="error">You are not authorized to view this application.</p><div class="clear"></div>');
            } else {
                    // SQL syntax error
                    printf("Prep statment failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        } else {
                    // Invalid LDAP user/pass
                    echo('<p class="error">Invalid username or password.</p><div class="clear"></div>');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You could try listening to the help we gave you in chat.

Comment: You are not closing the if-else statements, hence the parse error.

Comment: When you create if/else, writ the brackets *first* then insert the code. This way you can avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: Another option is to reduce the nesting by putting the code into functions. If you have too many brackets start a new function with the farthest nested block and work your way up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be more careful with your brackets. Try this:

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');

//error_reporting(0);
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $ldap = ldap_connect("localserv1.local.local.edu", 389) or exit("Error connecting to LDAP server.");

    //Settings for AD
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    //Check if user can access LDAP
    if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, 'local\\' . $username, $password)) {
        //Prep SQL statement
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM table WHERE username = ?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            // Check if the username is in table
            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

                // Log them in
                session_register("username");
                session_register("password");
                header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, -9) . "index.php");
                exit;
            } else {
                //User is not in table
                echo('<p class="error">You are not authorized to view this application.</p><div class="clear"></div>');
            }
        } else {
            // SQL syntax error
            printf("Prep statment failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
    } else {
        // Invalid LDAP user/pass
        echo('<p class="error">Invalid username or password.</p><div class="clear"></div>');
    }
}
?>
```

**PROTIP:** To avoid this in the future, write your brackets *first*, then put your code inside the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The `else` statement here:

```
} else {
    //User is not in table
    echo('<p class="error">You are not authorized to view this application.</p><div class="clear"></div>');
```

It's not closed - you need an extra closing brace. And indeed on the following else, too - you should indent the code properly, and this sort of thing is a lot easier to spot.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem may be the difficulty of reading curly braces tucked in at the starts and ends of lines. I know this is considered to be a valid style and no doubt an experienced eye is able to read it easily, but the layout below makes things much more visible -- at the cost of adding a few more blank lines. It's easy to see which if and which else match up AND it's easy to spot if there is a misplaced or dangling curly brace - a security gotcha in 2013 as I recall.

```
if (some condition)    
   {    
   if (another condition)
      {
      if (yet another condition)
         {
         things to do if some condition, another condition, and yet another condition are met
         }
      else
         {
         things to do if if some condition and another condition are met and yet another condition is not met 
         }
      }    
   else
      {
      list of things to do if some condition is met but if another condition is not met
      } 
   }
else    
   {
   list of things to do if some condition is not met
   }
```